# Can't use make and cmake on windows

Tags: windows, makefile, cmake, ogre

I am trying to compile ogre on windows 7 x64. It's only the sample tutorial.

The environnement var are:

```
BOOST_INCLUDEDIR=C:\OgreSDK\boost
BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=C:\OgreSDK\boost\lib
BOOST_ROOT=C:\OgreSDK\boost
OGRE_HOME=C:/OgreSDK
Path=...C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts...C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts...;C:/OgreSDK/bin/;C:\MinGW\bin
```

You can see the full ones here https://gist.github.com/vinz243/bf1a2465215c0fb906b0

The repo is here https://github.com/vinz243/ogre-test

So the output was:

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c

The output was:
1
```

Multiple times https://github.com/vinz243/ogre-test/blob/master/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log

Note that I must append

```
//CXX compiler.

CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe

//C compiler.

CMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe

// Make program
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=C:/MinGW/bin/make.exe
```

On each build b/c each build throws an error otherwise

Comment: It is a little unclear what you actually want. "Please debug my code or fix my errors" are usually not considered good questions on stackoverflow. That said, have you tried compiling a very simple test-project? For example, a  minimal cmake project or even a simple helloworld.cpp?

Comment: Check your CMake error log: It states that it cannot find a folder ("The output was: Le fichier spécifié est introuvable"), so one of the provided paths must be wrong. Basically, it does not look like an Ogre issue, but a general CMake problem on your end.

Comment: I think so, but it doesn't say what file unfortunately.@Andre I'm trying as soon as i can :)

Answer (score 0):

There were several problems

- In the PATH, the Git `bin/` folder was set, and it was conflicting w/ cmake
- CmdEr was making trouble, too. Stock cmd worked
- Cmd must be ran as admin